# Group action on subsets

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $S$ be a subset of $G$ that is NOT a subgroup. Let $a,b$ be elements of $G$.

If $aS = bS$, must $a = b$?

The actual question is:

Let the dihedral group $D_3$ act on the set of subsets of size $3$ of $D_3$ by left multiplication. Find the sizes of the orbits.

$D_3$ has one size $3$ subgroup, the orbit of this subgroup has size $2$ (we know this from Lagrange's theorem). I've written out the other orbits and get that there are $3$ other orbits of size 6. It seems to be the case that if $S$ is not a subgroup of $D_3$ then gS is different for each element $g$ of $D_3$. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: No, take $G = \mathbb{Z}_5$, $S = \{2, 3\}$, $a = 1$ and $b = 4$. You have $1S = S$ and $4S = S$ since $4 \cdot 2 = 3$ and $4 \cdot 3 = 2$.

Comment: @fran, you actually have $G={\bf Z}_5^{\times}$, the multiplicative group of the ring ${\bf Z}_5$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It seems that easily that $D_3$ doesn't act on the set $\Omega$ as it is defined transitively , so the group has more than one orbit and so $|D_3|=|\omega^{D_3}||{D_3}_{\omega}|$. Do you think this help the OP?

Comment: For an example of size 3 in $D_3$, which I prefer to think of as $S_3$, let $S=\{{(12),(13),(23)\}}$. Then $S$ is not a subgroup, but $(12)S=(13)S=(23)S$.

Comment: @Babak, I don't know what you mean by $\Omega$, nor by $\omega$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry. I mean the set of all subsets of size 3 in D_3

Comment: Sorry, I meant that S isn't a coset of any subgroup - OP

Comment: @099, if what you meant isn't what you asked, then you should edit your question so it reflects your intended meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The general framework appears to be that $a S = b S$ if and only if $a H = b H$, where the *subgroup* $H$ is the stabiliser of $S$ in the action of $G$ *on the left* on its subsets. So the question reduces to subgroups after all.

In particular, the question

> If $aS = bS$, must $a = b$?

has the answer

> Only when $H=1$.

**PS** And then perhaps one might note that for a subgroup $H$ and a subset $S$ we have $H S = S$ (that is, $H$ is a subgroup of the stabilizer of $S$) if and only if $S$ is a union of right cosets $H s$ of $H$.